# Clarification on mixins and implementations in Dart

Tags: dart, mixins

In [this article about Dart Mixins](https://v1-dartlang-org.firebaseapp.com/articles/language/mixins) there is an example at the bottom:

```
class S {
  twice(int x) => 2 * x;
}

abstract class I {
   twice(x);
}

abstract class J {
   thrice(x);
}
class K extends S implements I, J {
  int thrice(x) => 3* x;
}

class B {
  twice(x) => x + x;
}
class A = B with K;
```

The article goes on to say:

> Now when we define A, we get the implementation of thrice() from K’s
>   mixin. However, the mixin won’t provide us with an implementation of
>   twice(). Fortunately, B does have such an implementation, so overall A
>   does satisfy the requirements of I, J as well as S.

I don't undrestand *why* `B` needs to implement `twice`. Why does `K`'s `thrice` implementation get applied to `B` but its inherited `twice` implementation doesn't?

Comment: I don't think it *needs* to implement it. Have you tried removing it? I think it's to demonstrate which implementation is actually executed.

Comment: "However, the mixin won’t provide us with an implementation of twice()." - it's elaborated in the linked article

Comment: I edited my question with more info

Comment: The text is out-of-date. You cannot use `K` as a mixin in Dart 2. In Dart 1, a mixin derived from a class with a superclass other than `Object`, like `K`, would only contain the members *declared* in that class, so only the declaration of `thrice`, not the inherited `twice` from S. The class `A` is the mixin application of that mixin to `B`, `B with K`, which extends `B` with the same class body that `K` extended its super class with (and it would also requires `B` to implement `S`, so this is not valid Dart 1 either). The result would be `twice` from `B` and `thrice` from `K`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Notice that the linked article is out-dated and does not apply to Dart 2.)

The idea behind mixins is that "a mixin" is the difference between a class and its superclass.

For the class `K`, that difference is everything in its declartion after the extends clause:

```
                 implements I, J {
  int thrice(x) => 3* x;
}
```

When you then create a new class `A` by applying that mixin to a different class, `B`, as `class A = B with K;` then the resulting class becomes essentially:

```
class A extends B implements I, J {
  int thrice(x) => 3* x;
}
```

This class implements the interfaces `I` and `J`, and has a `twice` method inherited from `B` and a `thrice` method mixed in from `K`.

(This example is not valid Dart 2. In Dart 2, you cannot extract an interface from a class declaration with a super-class other than `Object`. To declare a mixin that has a notion of a super-class, you must use the `mixin` declaration:

```
mixin K on S implements I, J {
  int thrice(int x) => 3* x;
}

class B implements S {
  int twice(int x) => 2 * x;
}

class A = B with K;
```

).